# Convert smarty articles to wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, smarty

I have big number articles posting in [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), they are in sql like that:

```
INSERT INTO `article` (`id`, `cat_id`, `member_id`, `author`, `title`, `text`, `image`, `description`, `tags`, `dateline`, `visits`, `comments`, `active`, `homepage`, `comment`, `show_author`) VALUES
(1060, 1, 46, '', 'article title', 'article content', '', '', '', '1215045869', 325, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Now I need to convert it to wordpress like that:

```
INSERT INTO `ap_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(2859, 1, '2014-03-17 02:00:31', '2014-03-16 23:00:31', 'Post Content', 'Post Title', '', 'inherit', 'open', 'open', '', '2858-template-v1', '', '', '2014-03-17 02:00:31', '2014-03-16 23:00:31', '', 2858, 'http://www.sample.com/wp/2858-template-v1/', 0, 'template', '', 0);
```

Any Help?

Comment: Smarty is a templating engine, not a blog system, so I'm not sure what database structure you are referring to there. Is it just a home-made database?

Comment: Yes I think so, it is home-made!